# statically sized pages in Kindle Books

Tags: kindle, kindle-kdk

I'm writing a book with lots of diagrams and very little text.

I've tried uploading a PDF, but it appears that Kindle tries to OCR my PDF and then resize it automatically to the device it's on.

Using the Kindle Developer Kit, is it possible to do the following:

- define my book as a set of 1920x1080 pages
- tell kindle to *NOT* auto reflow my content

Thanks!

Comment: No OCR needed the text can be simply read as plain text from the PDF source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The KDK does support that using a ListPager, but the better solution would be to use KF8 (http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?docId=1000729511) to do fixed layout. In particular, you would define exactly the ratio of the pages that you want, and would put one image per page.

Amazon also has a [children's book example](http://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html/ref=amb_link_359635422_2?location=http://kindlegen.s3.amazonaws.com/Children%27sBookSample.zip&token=321FBC360D6D2CE41E4ED829508B1F8017D89641&source=standards&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=right-6&pf_rd_r=042QE8QAT07SEC38E6M9&pf_rd_t=1401&pf_rd_p=1346376842&pf_rd_i=1000729511) that shows how to format it for `kindlegen`.